# What is PostgreSQL Query Language Considered?

Tags: database, postgresql

When searching for Oracle query help I know to look for PLSql for Microsoft it is T-SQL. What is PostgreSQL query considered?

Comment: [The internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#Procedural_languages) and [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql.html)

Comment: The *query language* is SQL - just as in Oracle. PL/SQL in Oracle is *only* used for stored procedures and functions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But to make matters more fun, [Transact-SQL/TSQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189826(v=sql.90).aspx) *is* the SQL Server query language and it includes the procedural constructs found in the other PL/* languages.

Comment: @user2864740: yes I know. Microsoft - unlike many others (Postgres, Oracle, DB2, Firebird) - does not make a clear distinction between the query language and procedural language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the language is [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql.html) (per the manual):

> PL/pgSQL is a loadable procedural language for the PostgreSQL database system. The design goals of PL/pgSQL were to create a loadable procedural language ..

Comment: That's not the "query" language, it's the language for stored functions.

Comment: If he's referencing plsql for Oracle - I'm fairly certain this is what he means.

Comment: I think his reference to PL/SQL is also wrong.

Comment: @Zito: Perhaps you are not aware yet but you can [accept an answer formally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work "How does accepting an answer work?") if it actually solves your problem/answers your question. There's no rush, in fact you even don't have to do that to begin with, but it may help many in using this site efficiently.

Comment: Thanks; I am still learning my way around the site!